# when i save richtextbox into rtf file , it 's content exceed the page 's width

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

when i save richtextbox using code :

```
 richTextBox1.SaveFile("aaa.rtf");
```

it success , but when i check the file , i find the saved content exceed page margin ,

[image]

the exceeded grid is a table i create using rtf format , here is the grid 's code  :

```
@"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
\trowd\trgaph144
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx2000
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx4000
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx6000
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx8000
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx10000
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx12000
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx14000
\intbl\cell
Last Hour ASR\intbl\cell
Last Hour ACD\intbl\cell
Average ASR\intbl\cell
Average ACD\intbl\cell
Live ASR\intbl\cell
Live ACD\intbl\cell
\row"
```

anyone know how to set the page size in code , or other way to solve this problem ?

thanks

Comment: refer to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/617e103e-6d22-483e-9933-d1fe21d84977/problem-saving-flowdocument-as-rtf-lost-the-table-size?forum=wpf

Comment: Use smaller numbers for your cell width.  Change `\cellx2000` to `\cellx1500`.  Play with those numbers until you get what you want.